# Vlookup multiple tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to use `VLOOKUP` on mutiple tables like - if not found in Table1 search in Table2, if not found on Table3 and so on...

Something like:

```
VLOOKUP(A2;(C3:E5) | (F3:H5) | ... ;2,0)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Probably not helpful in your case but Google Spreadsheet can combine ranges like this `{C3:E5;F3:H5}`. I think in Excel you'll need VBA.

Comment: I wrote an answer about named ranges but it wont work with your data layout. If you are willing to use VBA the Union method would be a simple approach Application.Union(Range1, Range2, Range3).Name = "LookupRange" I hope that's about right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would work, but I suggest you have separate `VLOOKUPS` in separate cells so that you can see which table the value is coming from

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("what?",table1,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("what?",table2,2,0),0))
```

You can continue this pattern of `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(),IFERROR(VLOOKUP()...` a bunch of times if needed - *again, I don't recommend it though*

---

**Update** 
Another way you could do this would be to use **Multiple Consolidated Ranges**. Basically just a pivot table.

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select multiple consolidated ranges, click next
2. Click next again (create a single page field for me)
3. Add all of your ranges. In the image below that is table 1 and table 2 (with headings), then click finish.

A pivot table will be created which comprises your tables. The Pivot Table equivalent of `VLOOKUP` is `GETPIVOTDATA` so you can use that here to get any value from the pivot table

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Value",$A$5,"Row",A1,"Column","value")
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah good idea with the pivot, if combined with dynamically names ranges (if required) it would work well I think.